# Is is possible to download software with IP packets sent from another computer?

Tags: wireless-networking, file-download, packet-injection

I was wondering if a computer was connected to the internet but needed an application downloaded, Instead of physically going to the computer and downloading the software, could another computer remotely send IP packets to send the software on to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done on **any** OS by listening to sockets, where another computer would send the information about what software to download and upon receiving this information, the host would automatically download the software.

You can also consider **Remote management** software on Windows or **SSH** on Unix-based systems.

To send the software directly onto it can be done by combining sockets with FTP apps and such, however, it is not really efficient.